# Asking a Professor to sign me to a group

Tags: communication, projects

I have a class assignment coming up. On the syllabus, it was indicated that groups would be assigned this week. I assumed that the professor would be assigning groups. However, last week the professor said that we need to choose the people we work with and come to him afterwards. I don't know anyone in my class and have a class directly after and before. I asked a few people and they had already chosen their friends to work with.

I sent him a polite email last weekend, asking him If he knew of anyone looking for an extra group member since I've been having a difficult time finding a group. It's now Monday night and he still hasn't answered. I'm panicking now since groups are due tomorrow and I have no form of contact with anyone in my class to even try and form a group. What do I do?!

Comment: There is something important you might want to learn for the future: Get to know other people and socialize! This is always an important skill, no matter what do you in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Send another email stating that you have been unable to find anyone and have been refused by a few teams. You will try to "catch" him before class.

Then (choose one) if you don't get a suitable reply:

(a) Show up at his office in the morning before class and present the problem. Ask for a solution. I.e. "How should I proceed?"

(b) Catch the prof in the hall just before class and ask for a solution.

(c) When class is about to begin, raise your hand and ask for a solution.

(d) After class catch the prof and ask for a solution.

There isn't really much else you can do. Prefer a to b to c to d, I think. But, I assume the prof has seen this before. You might not be the only one with the problem so a group might be formed immediately.

Comment: The OP has classes immediately before and after this one, so (b) and (d) are not feasible in this particular case.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there is usually a "bit" of time between classes and profs have to get from one room to another... So that is an opportunity...

Comment: You can also stand up before class and ask loudly if anyone else needs a group. You are probably not the only one in this boat. I would also go to office hours and provide feedback to the instructor that setting up a DL for students to for groups from would be helpful for future classes.